# How to query a particular object without it's embedded objects or collections?

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I have a class, lets say Blarkar. Blarkar has an embed class kar. Sometimes when I query for an instance of Blarkar I want the complete object, but other times I don't need all its embed objects and their embed objects. How do I load an object without its embed objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. GAE loads an entity whole or not at all. Generally this is not a problem and you shouldn't try to optimize unless you know you have a real issue.  But if so, you can split your entity into multiple parts, eg User and UserExtraStuff.

There is a special type of query called a projection query, but this is not likely going to be useful - it lets you select some data out of an index without doing a full entity lookup. It's only useful in limited types of inequality queries. The data has to be in the index.